# Returning Dictionary as ICollection

Tags: c#, generics, collections, dictionary, icollection

I have a interface that can implement various collections and data types, it works fine with some collection but the dictionary is giving me issues, I'm guessing because the Dictionary is a little different and has key value pairs?

```
public interface IStructure
{
    void InsertRun<T> (T item);
    ICollection RetrieveSortedListRun<T>();
    T RetrieveItemRun<T>(T item);
}

class DictionaryRun : IStructure
{
    IDictionary<int, object> dictionary;

    public DictionaryRun()
    {
        dictionary = new Dictionary<int, object>();
    }

    public void InsertRun<T>(T item)
    {
        dictionary.Add(dictionary.Count + 1, item);
    }

    public ICollection RetrieveSortedListRun<T>()
    {
        return dictionary;
    }

    public T RetrieveItemRun<T>(T item)
    {
        return item;
    }
}
```

Comment: Okay...so how are you using the `ICollection` and what problems are you having that prevent it from working at the moment?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`IDictionary<TKey, TValue>` does not implement `ICollection`, it implements `ICollection<KeyValuePair<TKey, TValue>>`.

As is, if you changed your dictionary to be a `IDictionary` your code would compile.

However, it seems to me that your overall design of the interface and the object could be reworked.

```
public interface IStructure<T>
{
  void InsertRun(T item);
  ICollection<T> RetrieveSortedListRun();
  T RetrieveItemRun(T item);
}


class DictionaryRun<T> : IStructure<T>
{
  IDictionary<int, T> dictionary;

  public DictionaryRun()
  {
    dictionary = new Dictionary<int, T>();
  }

  public void InsertRun(T item)
  {
    dictionary.Add(dictionary.Count + 1, item);
  }

  public ICollection<T> RetrieveSortedListRun()
  {
    return dictionary.Values;
  }

  public T RetrieveItemRun(T item)
  {
    return item;
  }
}
```

Comment: Seems to work great, I'm having issues when Implementing other collections such as array list and hashtable and trying to return them in the RetrieveSortedList method. Do arraylist and hashtable not implement ICollection<T> but just ICollection? This programs purpose is to measure efficiency of various data structures. I should do abit of reading into how to use different Collections and interfaces together.

Comment: @Kosmo `ArrayList` and `Hashtable` do implement just `ICollection`, there are typed options like `List<T>` and `HashSet<T>` you could look at which do implement `ICollection<T>`.

Answer (score 1):

A `Dictionary<TKey,TValue>` implements `ICollection<KeyValuePair<TKey,TValue>>` not `ICollection<TValue>`. It seems that you are never using the key, so why not use a `HashSet<T>` instead? `HashSet<T>` implements `ICollection<T>`.

---

**UPDATE**

Your code line

```
dictionary.Add(dictionary.Count + 1, item);
```

lets me think that all you need is an ordered list. In contrast to a sorted list, which sorts the list according to a key, the ordered list keeps the original insert order. So you probably do best by using a `List<T>`.

Comment: I agree, if you are never using the key into the dictionary, why even use a dictionary.  If you want to allow duplicates use List<T>, if don't want to allow duplicates use HashSet<T>

Answer (score 0):

Yes but Dictionary has a method to convert itself to a List, which implements ICollection:

```
public ICollection RetrieveSortedListRun<T>()
{
    return dictionary.ToList();
}
```

This will return a collection of `KeyValuePair`s.

Comment: `Dictionary<TKey, TValue>` does not define the `ToList()` method, it is defined as an extension method by `System.Linq.Enumerable`. Documentation: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb342261.aspx